# Mapbox GeoCoding keyword issue

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

Hi I have an app which uses Mapbox, I am also using geocoding to search places and to navigate to the location. It was working smoothly until I tried the keyword "Nayara" in the searchField. [image] [image]

I am getting this error when I search "Nayara" in the textfield, the textFieldIsChanging delegate is connected to the GeoCoding API(which is async communication and result is populated in the tableView). I can successfully search all other places but not this one. Is this a bug in the map box? Is this the only one keyword which has problems or are there any other keywords which makes the app behave like this? Expert advices needed. Thanks in advance. Happy coding.

Comment: When I tried to print the object "Identifier" what I saw is that when I type nayara then identifier's prefix has a space infront of the identifier, like this " Q" but when I tried other keywords the prefix is "Q", without space. So I believe when they look for the prefix Q we don't have a prefix Q when you type 'nayara'. I guess this is why MBPlaceMark class raised an error like this.

Answer (score 1):

When making multiple async requests, it's possible for the responses to be returned in a different order from the order in which they were requested. This is particularly an issue when requests take a variable amount of time (as is the case for geocoding queries).

In this situation, a query for `Nayar` probably takes longer than a query for `Nayara`, and the difference is enough that the results arrive out of order, so the `Nayar` response overwrites `Nayara` in the UI dropdown.

Typical solutions to this problem involve either adding a debounce (so that you only make a new API request if an arbitrary amount of time has elapsed between keystrokes), or tracking the timestamp of both the request and the response, and discarding stale responses that arrive out of order.

An example of the latter approach can be seen here: https://github.com/mapbox/react-geocoder/pull/9

Comment: What you are saying is that the typing speed does matters when using geocoding right? But when you type slowly then also this issue occurs! I guess this is a mapbox issue.